# To find zero set of an integral.

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

For an integrable function $f$ we define $$F(x)=\int^l_{-l}f(x-t)dt.$$
What is the relation between the set $\mathcal{Z}_F,\mathcal{Z}_f?$ ($\mathcal{Z}_F$ is the zero set of $F$)

My work: If $f$ vanishes on the set $E$ then $F$ vanishes on the set $$\bigcap_{-l\leq t\leq l}t+E,$$ where  $t+E=\{t+e:e\in E\}.$

Comment: Could you please clarify what set you intend by $\bigcap_{-l\leq t\leq l}t+E$?

Comment: Because if $x-t\in E,$ for all $-l\leq t \leq l$ then $F(x)=0$. But there is a difference between  $\mathcal{Z}(F)$ and $F$ vanishes on some set.